# Divide money value for payment (PHP)

Tags: php, math, division

First I thought this was a stupid question, and i should do some search and it would be easy to solve. But I am afraid I just ain't getting anywhere!

The thing i need to do is simple. I have a U$ value and i want to divide it by 12. Thats it.

Well, the thing is that this value is outputed by a function, and echoes ok, look:

```
<?php 
$preconormal = wpsc_the_product_price(); // it echoes like 99.90

$precoja = str_replace (".", "", $preconormal); 

echo $precoja; //echo ok -> 9990

$quantas = '12';

$parcela = $precoja/$quantas; // ok, so divide 9990 by 12, right?

echo $parcela; //no!!!!! it echoes 0 :(

?>
```

I really hope you can help me!

Comment: try `(int)$precoja/(int)$quantas`

Comment: `$precoja` is a string you'll need to float it to an integer `(int)$precoja`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to divide strings, if you used numbers say

$quantas = 12;
$precoja = 9990;

What happens?

It should fix the division, in which case, prior to the mathmematics, convert your vars to integs by

```
 $quantas = intval($quantas);
 $precoja = intval($precoja);
 //your manipulation here..l
```

Comment: well, it acctualy works then o.O' result:  832.5 maybe $precoja isn't being recon as an Int?

Comment: Exactly, i updated my answer to show you how to convert your vars from strings to ints prior to mathmatical manipulation

Comment: <?php 
         $preconormal = wpsc_the_product_price(); 
         $precoja = str_replace (".", "", $preconormal);
         $quantas = 12; 
         $quantas = intval($quantas);
         $precoja1 = intval($precoja);
            $parcela = $precoja1 / 12;
            echo $parcela;
                   
         ?> it gives me 0

Comment: Echo $precoja, what value is it giving?

Comment: Also , not sure it matters but put your equation in parintheses like echo ( $precoja1 / 12);

Comment: echo $precoja outputs 9990 then i use $precoja1 = intval($precoja)/ echo $precoja1 shows 0.

Comment: $precoja ...not sure which you are referring to now, the original or the first...so, lets o back to assgining them hardcoded vals...set $precoja =9990 and remove any precoja intval stuff, and execute echo ( $precoja / 12);

Comment: Yeah, that works, actually. the prlbm is probably at the wpsc_the_product_price(); it echos 99.0 but I srtreplace the ., making it a string 990 but cant convert it to INT to divide it

Comment: thanks, i figured it out, the curency simbol was echoed by wpsc_the_product_price, not only bumbers

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes...

```
$quantas = '12';
```

to

```
$quantas = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$precoja = floatval($preconormal)*100;
$preconormal = $precoja / 12;
```

Comment: I appreciate it trying to help me, but it outputed 0 also

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your 5th line by removing the single quotes and/or 6th line with `$parcela = (int)$precoja / (int)$quantas;` because as soon as you use the function `str_replace` then $precoja becomes a string. Also having the single quotes earlier on  `= '12'` it is also a string and that division returns 0.

Comment: I understand the logic and really apreciate it, but it still gives me 0

Comment: How is that possible, I have tried your example (given 99.90 to $precoja) and it worked fine given final output 83.25! Try removing the `wpsc_the_product_price()` and put 99.90 and if it is fixed then you know your problem is at `wpsc_the_product_price()` function. Perhaps make sure that function returns proper result type.

Comment: I think that is the point.. but wpcs_the_product_price() does show the result 99.90.....